# Display 5 content in LINQ and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am newbei on LINQ. I want to display higher viewed 5 content. I already have Viewed field on my table and it will increase 1 by 1 if user click on ReadMore button.

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: if you notice, you get negative scores on your questions-- that is because you don't know how to ask the smart questions. post a snippet of the code you're working on then explain your problem a lot clearer.

Comment: While I'm agree with @MartinOngtangco about not very constructive question, you still got right answer from L.B. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Viewed).Take(5)
```